# IF there is 24 hours between dates CASE statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a case statment saying if 1 day or less has passed between my 2 date parameters then do this otherwise do this.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, however this only works in a query

```
case when datediff(hh,@Date1,@Date2) < 24 then.....
```

if it is in regular non query T-SQL just use an IF statement

```
IF datediff(hh,@Date1,@Date2) < 24  
begin
-- stuff here
end
else
begin
-- stuff here
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Explain "do this", because a [CASE expression doesn't control flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(d1-d2 AS FLOAT) > 1 THEN '> 1 Day' ELSE '<= Day' END
```